# pyrogram does not copy messages from channels

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

The bot is launching. But it does not copy messages from the specified channels. For testing I created a new channel, I write messages there and they are not copied, but if I add the bot to the channel with administrator rights, then after that new messages from the channel are copied successfully.
Everything was working fine a few days ago.
Now I sent my code to a friend, he did the same steps and his messages are copied normally without adding the bot to the channel with admin rights.
Anybody run into this? Help me, please.

The bot should copy messages from channels without admin rights.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.